# How do I get extract a class file to get classes inside that class file?

Tags: java, javascript, class, import, io

How do I get class files from a class file? If I'm not wrong SOME classes have other classes inside them. But I can't get those class files. How do I extract a class file?

Comment: what do you mean by "get classes" ?

Comment: Inner classes, non-public classes in the same file, etc. get their own class file. What are you trying to do?

Comment: After reviewing your other questions per Tony's comment, the best way you could help us help you is by providing details on what, precisely, your goal is. "Extracting a class" doesn't really make any sense at your level of experience. Are you looking for the source of the Java run time libraries? Are you trying to use those classes? Are you trying to understand where on the filesystem those classes are (answered; in rt.jar)?

Comment: Are you just trying to instantiate an Inner class? In that case Xeon's answer is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean get compiled inner classes files:
Compiled inner classes are in different `.class` file usually with `$1`, `$2` etc. ending.

Look at [this javaspecialists.eu](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue192b.html)

If you mean - "how to use inner classes":

```
new OuterClass.InnerClass(...);
```

Inner class must be visible from the code you are invoking it. (public, package)

Answer (score 0):

If you have JAR fles, you can use an unzip program (like WINZIP) to take them apart.  Class files.. no way that I know of.

I get the idea you're solving the wrong problem, however.